# how i use array from code behind to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, code-behind

i try to do something and i cant success.
i have page with a many radio button. all 3 radio buttons is for one click to choose.i want to know what is the value of specific radio button where user click.
for that i try to get a array from code behind to js and then its can help me to find the id of every radio button. 
 the radio button come with id and part of id is varible "Game". the varible Game this is what i want to get from code behind to JS

my code behind:

//create array and return string with radio batton tag

**how i pass the array "Game" to JS?**

```
public string  GetList()
{

string str="";

    string[] Game=New string[5];
    string[0]="111";
    string[1]="222";
    string[2]="333";
    string[3]="444";
     string[4]="555"

for (i=0;i<Game.length;i++){

 str = "<input type = 'radio' id='1_option_Game[i]' name='ForecastRadio_'" + Game[i] + " value='1'>";

str+= "<input type = 'radio' id='2_option_Game[i]' name='ForecastRadio_'" + Game[i] + " value='2'>";

str+= "<input type = 'radio' id='3_option_Game[i]' name='ForecastRadio_'" + Game[i] + " value='3'>";
}

return str;
    }
```

html:

//show the radio button from code behind . one input field for game

```
<div>
  //value Game1.. here i want the value of radio button its will appear
    <input   id= "Game1" runat="server"/>

  </div>

<div >
  value Game2
    <input   id= "Game2" runat="server"/>

  </div>

    <div>
    the radio button list:
        <%=GetList()>

    </div>
```

js:
**//here i need to get the Game array**

//if user click on one of radio button he get the value and pass to input field

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     // this array i want to get from code behind i dont know here what the value inside 
            var Game = ["111", "222", "333", "444", "555"];


            for (i = 0; i < Game.length; i++) {

               //just 1 example.. i know i need more 2       
               $('#1_option_'+Game[i]).click(function () {

                 //show the value in input field
 var val = document.getElementById('<%=Game1.ClientID%>'); val.value = ($(this).val());

                 });
}

            });
```

***i do it in codepen*** (witout code behind) just for know how its look.
https://codepen.io/alexx11x/pen/zWLqry

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong direction. You can find controls based on class with javascript and read the id if thats the only thing you need. Also you can add the values to the radiobuttons and then just read the value instead of making it complex with adding a seperate array

Comment: I need to find the id and get the value. In my average page i have approximately 21 radio button so i must find the id (from array list) and then the value